# changing login source to panel login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, modalpopupextender, loginstatus

I have created a login system in a panel that has the modal Pop up extender that displays when i click the login linkbutton. I have also set up a login status to view whether the person has login or logged out.

when a person logs in with the login page in the panel that has modal pop up, when he logs in the login status shows that the person that has been logged in..
like

**someone [Logout]**

when i click log out, a login link button appears that goes to the page that i have deleted i.e the automatically created login page in the accounts folder (~/accounts/login.aspx).

i want it to go to the panel instead of that page

how can change this..

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Master.Master/panel" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

and it shows two login linkbuttons, one that i have created and the second that appears after clicking the logout link in the login status

i want to hide this second login button in the login status
in short i want only one login system through modal pop up panel

please give me a solution to this..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it that way.

What you can do is roll your own solution. Since you already have a master page, have it check if the user is logged in or not when it loads (probably in the Page_Load event or earlier). If the user is logged in you show his credentials and the log out button, if not you display the pop up.